# How remove whitespace or set width on facebook chatbot quickreplies

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-chatbot

I'm creating a rating chatbot for Facebook messenger.

Unfourtunately I'm getting different results on android and iOS.

on iOS and web I'm getting the quick replies like this.:
[image]

on Android I'm getting a large button with scroll.
[image]

Can I remove the leading space after the number on android or set the min width??

The code I'm using is:

```
quick_replies: [ 
        { content_type: 'text', title: '0',  payload: `0-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '1',  payload: `1-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '2',  payload: `2-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '3',  payload: `3-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '4',  payload: `4-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '5',  payload: `5-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '6',  payload: `6-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '7',  payload: `7-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '8',  payload: `8-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '9',  payload: `9-${key}` },
        { content_type: 'text', title: '10', payload: `1-|${key}` }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but please open a bug report on the unexpected whitespace on android:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/